# HTML using Groovy MarkupBuilder, how do I elegantly mix tags and text?

Tags: html, groovy

When using Groovy `MarkupBuilder`, I have places where I need to output text into the document, or call a function which outputs text into the document. Currently, I'm using the undefined tag *"text"* to do the output.  Is there a better way to write this code?

```
li {
  text("${type.getAlias()} blah blah ")
  function1(type.getXYZ())
  if (type instanceof Class1) {
    text(" implements ")
    ft.getList().each { 
      if (it == '') return
      text(it) 
      if (!function2(type, it)) text(", ")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Actually, the recommended way now is to use `mkp.yield`, e.g.,

```
src.p {
    mkp.yield 'Some element that has a '
    strong 'child element'
    mkp.yield ' which seems pretty basic.'
}
```

to produce

```
<p>Some element that has a <strong>child element</strong> which seems pretty basic.</p>
```

Comment: What is mkp? is that the instance of MarkupBuilder?

Comment: @DavidW: No it is not! It woud produce `<yield> the text ... </yield>`. `mkp` is a special namespace used to escape away from the normal building mode of the builder and get access to helper markup methods such as `yield` and `yieldUnescaped`. See http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/xml/MarkupBuilder.html#getMkp()

Answer (score 2):

Include a method:

```
void text(n){
    builder.yield n
}
```

Most likely you (I) copied this code from somewhere that had a text method, but you didn't also copy the text method.  Since MarkupBuilder accepts any name for the name of a tag and browsers ignore unknown markup, it just happened to work.

Comment: Note that it works only when `builder` is not an instance of the `MarkupBuilder`...