# Groovy MarkupBuilder - not yielding raw text

Tags: html, grails, groovy, taglib, markupbuilder

I have the following chunk of code for writing out a series of button elements, containing an icon and text:

```
def tagcloud = { attrs, body ->

    def mb = new MarkupBuilder(out)

    mb.ul('class': 'list-inline') {
        def tag = it
        attrs.tags.split(",").each {
            li {
                button('class': 'btn btn-default', 'type': 'submit') {
                    i('class': 'fa fa-tag', '')
                    mb.yield('test')
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am finding when using the yield function that the markup builder is outputting the yield call as a tag in my html, rather then the raw text:

```
<li>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
      <i class="fa fa-tag"></i>
      <yield>test</yield>
    </button>
</li>
```

Based on my research, this is the recommended way of doing this: [HTML using Groovy MarkupBuilder, how do I elegantly mix tags and text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23169/html-using-groovy-markupbuilder-how-do-i-elegantly-mix-tags-and-text)

Does anyone know why this text is being wrapped liked this?

I am using Grails 2.3.8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply this way:

```
def tagcloud = { attrs, body ->

    def mb = new MarkupBuilder(out)

    mb.ul('class': 'list-inline') {
        def tag = it
        attrs.tags.split(",").each {
            li {
                button('class': 'btn btn-default', 'type': 'submit') {
                    i('class': 'fa fa-tag', '')
                    mkp.yield('test')
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

mkp is a special namespace used to escape away from the normal building mode of the builder and get access to helper markup methods such as 'yield' and 'yieldUnescaped'. See the [javadoc for getMkp()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.2/html/gapi/groovy/xml/MarkupBuilder.html) for further details.